# Defining setter return value

Tags: encapsulation, setter, getter

I just had a problem in one of my projects. Maybe I got the wrong concept about encapsulation.
Encapsulation protects member variables from classes, by defining getters and setters methods, now, i was reading that setters must be void, but in that case, how can I know if the function really set the value passed by argument. For example

```
void setArea(int a) {
  if(a>0)
    Area = a;
}
```

How can I be sure that argument "a" was a correct value, wouldnt be better defining the function like this

```
bool setArea(int a) {
  if(a>0) {
    Area = a;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Is that ok? that way i can know if a change really happened.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a [guard clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause) that throws an exception if invalid values are set:

```
void setArea(int a) {
  if (a <= 0) throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);
  Area = a;
}
```

But if you want client code to test for invalid values *before* setting them, you could have this:

```
bool isAreaValid(int a) {
  return a > 0;
}

void setArea(int a) {
  if (!isAreaValid(a)) throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);
  Area = a;
}
```

Clients could be coded like this:

```
if (obj.isAreaValid(myArea)) {
  obj.setArea(myArea);
}
```

But don't stop there. If the *concept* of area is important, spring it into existence into its own [*value object*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject) to make your design clearer.